# Poetry config and publish are broken for me

Tags: python, pypi, python-poetry

I'm on a new Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.  I've installed Poetry.  (Initially v1.5.1, but when I ran into this problem, I upgraded to v1.6.1 to see if it fixed anything - it didn't.)

The problem is whenever I try to use `poetry config pypi-token.pypi "MYTOKEN"` to store my PyPI token, it says nothing, and does nothing.

I had to use `poetry config cache-dir "/tmp"` (changing a different official setting) to force it to create the `~/config/pypoetry/config.toml` file, then manually added my token to the same file, but when I run `poetry config --list`, it shows the modified value for `cache-dir` but mentions nothing about the `pypi-token.pypi` setting.

Furthermore, when I delete `config.toml` and then cd to the dir containing my PyPI library (which I've previously published on a previous desktop where I *was* able to config poetry properly), it behaves as if everything's fine:

```
ofer@minime:~/src/odigity/py-objects$ poetry publish

Publishing py-objects (0.0.2) to PyPI
 - Uploading py_objects-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl 100%
 - Uploading py_objects-0.0.2.tar.gz 100%
```

Even though the version hasn't been updated since my last publish, and I very clearly have *no credentials configured*.

I'm so confused.  Everything seems broken at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm way out of my depth here, but I dug through source and dabbled with the debugger and learned Poetry uses an OS keyring service called "poetry-repository-pypi", and apparently chose to store my token in there instead of writing to/reading from the `config.toml` file.

```
$ ~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin/python /usr/bin/keyring get poetry-repository-pypi __token__
pypi-AgEI[...SNIPPED...]X8dA
```

It still doesn't explain:

- why Poetry doesn't create the `config.toml` file as promised by the docs
- why the `poetry config --list` command refuses to show me my previously-set token, despite the fact that it obviously finds it during the publish operation
- why Poetry doesn't say anything (not even a warning) when publishing a package version that you've already published